# In jQuery Mobile, how do you target the element created using loadPage?

Tags: callback, jquery-mobile

I load a "page" into the DOM using `$.mobile.loadPage()`. I then want to target the element created, but I haven't figured out how to do this. This is what I thought would work:

```
var toc = $.mobile.loadPage('toc.html');
toc.trigger('customevent');
```

The above does not work in part because `toc` is a "deferred promise object" rather than a good ol' jQuery DOM reference. Additionally, it does not work because the second line is triggered before loadPage finishes. Is there a way to fire a callback after loadPage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the id of the page being loaded then you can bind the 'pagecreate' event to that object with `.live()` like so:

```
$('#blah').live('pagecreate', function () {alert('created');});
```

This will fire after the page has been loaded into the dom.

Answer (score 0):

I just was just able to figure this out, even if you don't have the id, here's an example of how i am performing an action (fadeIn) on the the inserted element....

```
$(document).bind('pageload',function(evt,data){ 
    $(document).unbind('pageload');  
    $(data.page).fadeIn(); 
});
$.mobile.loadPage('mypage.html',{'pageContainer':$('#my_item')});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `pageshow` in order to fire a callback when the page is loaded. Please refer to the [jQuery Mobile Events API](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) for more detail.

An example would be something like:

```
$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
    ...
});
```